# web.config to route all request to index.php except for physical files and directories

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, iis, web-config

im trying to upload a php script to  windows iis server 
in php script we have a htacess file which routes all the request to index.php so we can have

site.com/something

instead of

site.com/index.php?/something

but it doesnt work on the windows server so i tried to find web.config version here is what i found

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Quitar los slash '/' del final de la ruta -->
        <rule name="RewriteRequestsToPublic">
          <match url="^(.*)$" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:0}" />
        </rule>

        <!-- Si el archivo o carpeta solicitado no existe, se realiza la petición a través de index.php -->
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

it kinda works , but it doesn't load static files (css , js ) like if i go to

site.com/public/js/jquery.js

i get this error

```
HTTP Error 500.52 - URL Rewrite Module Error.
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
Detailed Error Information
Module  RewriteModule
Notification    SendResponse
Handler StaticFile
Error Code  0x800700b7
Config Error    Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'rule' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'Imported Rule 1'
Config File \\?\C:\HostingSpaces\phoenarts\site.com\wwwroot\public\web.config
```

basically it works i need to tell it to ignore link to directory and static files files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error implies you already have a rule declared with the name `Imported Rule 1` somewhere.  Try changing the name of the rule in the file indicated in the error.

If you have a web.config file in ~/public and another in the web root both files are merged for requests to your static assets. This sounds like what's happening?

You can use multiple web.configs to configure different paths like this, but you shouldnt duplicate rules between them.

You can also use `<location>` elements in the root web.config to configure different paths (as an alternative to using multiple web.config files).